# Is there a function to find the source of #DIV/0! and #NUM! errors in a huge Excel file?

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, excel-formula, excel-2010

Description of the Excel Worksheet:

I’ve got an economic model with 130 simultaneous equations in Excel. A typical equation looks like the following:

```
x_t = constant1 * y_t-1

y_t = constant2 * x_t-1 + constant3 * u _t-1
```

Example function:

```
=INDEX(tfp_e;1;DS$2)  * INDEX(kc_m;1;DR$2)^INDEX(alfae_e;1;DS$2)  * ((INDEX(lftr_e;1;DS$2)  * (1  - INDEX(utr_e;1;DS$2))  * INDEX(epratio_e;1;DS$2))^(1  - INDEX(alfae_e;1;DS$2)))
```

- Iteration is allowed in the Worksheet.
- It contains 130.000 cells.
- All the calculations are almost perfect. The average of error is nearly -1.3E-08.

However, in the case of 12 variables, if I just press an ENTER while staying in the cell, then the whole model goes wrong. #DIV/0! and #NUM! errors appears in the cells.

---

My question is that how can I trace back the source of the error? Is there a function to apply in this situation? I think somewhere I missed a bracket or misspelled a range, but I’ve checked all the variables a thousand times.

Comment: Who downvoted? This is a perfectly valid (and somewhat interesting) question.

Comment: This may help point you in the right direction. It won't be a function (but I am fairly certain a function for this purpose would be immensely complex anyways) but it is an in-built tool that Excel offers: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/video-use-trace-to-fix-formula-errors-689e22fc-9886-46c0-87ca-1fb626ec87e9.

Comment: Thank you, Brandon! Sadly, I've already tried these tracing arrows, but my models is so complex that this gives me limited clue about the errors.

Answer (score 2):

A great way to narrow down the issue is to use the Evaluate Formula option under Formulas/Formula Auditing.

Press evaluate, if you want to move further in evaluation: this will calculate the currently underlined part.

Press Step in/Step out, if you want to dig deeper into parts of the formula.